# Need to press OC touch power button on every boot Gigabyte GA-Z170X SOC force

Tags: reboot, overclocking, powersave

I bought a GIGABYTE motherboard a month ago. It has Overclocking features. On every reboot I need to press the OC Power button to get the GIGABYTE motherboard flash screen. When I press that OC power button, the orange light flashes off from the motherboard and the system starts. If I don't do that, it tells me D-SUB entering into power saving mode.

Why do I need to press that OC power button every time while booting up the system?

OS - Win 10 64 bit
CPU - i7 6700k
Mother board - GIGABYTE GA-Z170X-SOC FORCE
Monitor - LG 20M38 (Using HDMI cable)

Answer (score -1):

It could be possible that you haven't connected your Power Switch cable to your Motherboard properly. It could cause these errors. :>

Comment: Here is the Oc Touch power button which I need to press -

http://www.gigabyte.com/FileUpload/Features/2/Photo/5142.jpg
when I press this then only the system starts.

Comment: yes. I know what is the OC power button. What i am saying is, have you connected all the wires properly and tightly. If not, it might be a motherboard problem and you gotta get a refund